# Performance: why is the first implementation of the same algorithm significantly faster

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance

The algorithm is taken from LeetCode: https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-product-of-word-lengths/description/

Here is the jsperf I created (I have some local tests which gives the same result): https://jsperf.com/maximum-product-of-word-lengths

Here is the first "slow" implementation:

```
function maxProduct (words) {
    if (!words || !words.length) return 0;
    let len = words.length;
    let values = [];
    // console.log(values)
    for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        let tmp = words[i];
        let num = 0, len = tmp.length;
        for (let j = 0; j < len; ++j) {
            num |= 1 << (tmp.charCodeAt(j) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0));
        }
        values[i] = {
            num: num,
            len: tmp.length
        };
    }

    let maxProduct = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        for (let j = 0; j < len; ++j) {
            if ((values[i].num & values[j].num) == 0) {
                maxProduct = Math.max(maxProduct, values[i].len * values[j].len);
            }
        }
    }
    return maxProduct;
  };
```

Here is the "fast" implementation:

```
 function maxProductFast (words) {
      var temp = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
          var tempObj = {};
          tempObj.item = words[i];

          var num = 0;
          for(var j = 0; j < words[i].length; j++){
              num |= 1 << (words[i].charCodeAt(j) - 97);
          }

          tempObj.num = num;
          temp.push(tempObj);
      }

      var res = 0;

      for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
          for(var j = i + 1; j < temp.length; j++){
              var item1 = temp[i];
              var item2 = temp[j];

              if((item1.num & item2.num) == 0) {
                  res = Math.max(res, item1.item.length * item2.item.length);
              }

          }
      }

      return res;
  }
```

Comment: Loops are different, less method calls...

Comment: here's the problem with benchmarks like this ... in firefox `maxProductFast` is 21% **slower** than `maxProduct`

Comment: @JaromandaX Same here. On Firefox 57 (Developer Edition) on Debian, `maxProductFast` is 25% slower.

Comment: @EvilTak - I thought `Developer Edition` was a given on SO - don't **all** developers use the developer edition? :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not the same. The second algorithm has a loop with a complexity of (n*(n+1))/2 where each progressive step is from i+1 to the length of temp. the first algorithm has a two nested for loops each with a cost of n^2. the complexity of both will reduce to O(n^2). I believe that both of these will have a similar performance with a significantly large enough set.

The reason you would do n+1 for each sub iteration is because you are trying to find the max of any pair of items. if you place your elements in a grid you will notice that any diagonal pair a_3 * a_2 = a_2 * a_3 produces the same value. you can basically halve the collection and save a few cycles.

Comment: Silly me for not noticing that and thought of all kinds of ways to micro-optimize it. Thank you!